# Error 12 Declined returned in PayFlow

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

Error 12 Declined returned in PayFlow.
What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

what amount are you using? Is it the test server and are the cards from the test documentation? Verify all cards are correct and try an amount under $25.00. If the issue is something else let me know.